# Using Plink, how to auto-input password into Ubuntu ssh?

Tags: shell, batch-file, ssh, sudo, plink

I'm currently setting up a batch file to ssh from a Windows machine into a Ubuntu machine and issue a series of commands. I'm using plink, and I'm using the `-m` argument to pass a .txt file with a list of commands.

The batch file code that runs through `cmd`:

```
set PATH=c:\path\to\plink.exe
plink.exe -ssh -t user@ipaddress -pw <psw> -m c:\path\to\textFile\commands.txt
```

The `commands.txt` code:

```
sudo -s      #access the root login
<root psw>   #enter the password for the root login
command-1    #issue a command in linux as root
command-2    #issue a command in linux as root
command-3    #issue a command in linux as root
```

The issue I'm running into is that when I run this batch file, the output within command prompt still prompts the user to manually enter the password. Is there a means to input the password form the next line of the `commands.txt` file? Or does this process require something else?

Comment: You could consider modifying the `/etc/sudoers` file on the Ubuntu machine to include `NOPASSWD` for this user.

Answer (score 2):

As even your question says, the file `commands.txt` specified by `-m` switch should contain *commands*. A *password* is not a *command*.

Moreover, the commands in the file are executed one-by-one. The `sudo` (had it worked) would execute an interactive shell session and wait for a user input (commands). Only once the `sudo` exits, the following commands (`command-1`, etc) are executed.

---

Automating password input for `sudo` is generally a bad idea. If you need to run some commands that require root privileges, a better solution is to associate a dedicated private key with the commands in `sudoers` file. And then use `sudo` and the private key in Plink.

---

Anyway, to automate an input (of a password in this case) to a command, you need to use an input redirection. The same is true for commands to be executed within (not after) `sudo`.

Like:

```
(
    echo passwod
    echo command-1
    echo command-2
) | plink.exe -ssh -t user@ipaddress -pw <psw> sudo -s
```

As now there's only one real top-level command - `sudo`, I'm specifying it directly on Plink command-line, instead of using `-m` switch. Functionally, it's identical.